# Yeoman Polymer for Polymer 0.8

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I am using Yeoman to scaffold my Polymer project. I upgraded Polymer and everything else to 0.8-preview, and the application stopped working.

What changes in the application should I do to make 0.8-preview working?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Any information you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: @Andy no error, there is no template-bound event fired.

Comment: We need to see some sample code like what components do you use, etc .. there could be a hundred reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are my notes on the conversion process from Polymer 0.5 to 0.8.

#### See Polymer 0.8 Migration Guide

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html

#### HTML Conversion Process

1. polymer-element to dom-module
2. polymer-element name to

   polymer-element attribute/property camelCase to dash-case

   polymer-element attributes="xxx xxxx" add to javascript properties

   polymer-element layout `<polymer-element name="x-foo" layout horizontal wrap>`

   - add `<link rel="import" href="../layout/layout.html">` to top with other imports
   - add hostAttributes `hostAttributes: {class: "layout horizontal wrap"}` to Polymer({

   polymer-element move up `<link rel="import" type="css" href="my-awesome-button.css">` from `<template> to <dom-module>`

   polymer-element move up `<style></style>` from `<template>` to `<dom-module>`

   - see www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/local-dom.html

   template repeat to is="x-repeat" and repeat= to items= (temporary)

   - see www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/experimental.html

   template is="auto-binding"  to is="x-binding"  (temporary)

   template if= to is="x-if" (temporary) or use diplay block or none

   textContent binding from `<div>First: {{first}}</div>` TO `<span>{{first}}</span><br>`

   elements `on-click="{{handleClick}}"` to `on-click="handleClick"`

#### Javascript Conversion Process

1. polymer-element name to Polymer({ is:
2. polymer-element attributes="" to javascript `properties: { }`

#### CSS Conversion Process

1. polymer-element move up `<style></style>` from `<template>` to `<dom-module>` (as noted above)

   - see www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html#styling

#### Difference example of paper-button conversion by Polymer team

http://chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/compare-code.html?el=paper-button

Comment: These conversion steps are a work in progress and don't cover every step yet. For my latest conversion steps see https://github.com/chuckh/road-to-polymer/blob/master/conversion.md.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good write up between 0.5 and 0.8 - maybe that helps: https://divshot.com/blog/web-components/polymer-0-8-sneak-peek/

Comment: I think the  biggest change in 0.8 is the Component registration change... so you might have to rewrite some of your custom components.

Comment: Here is probably the biggest statement: "I'm not going to lie, if you're building stuff with Polymer the transition to 0.8 is going to hurt, bad. There's very little that won't need to be rewritten significantly (if not from scratch)."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not upgrade the 3rd party code to *preview* versions without thoughtful examination of changelog. Generally.

In `0.8`, which is claimed to be the `1.0`-release candidate, there has changed virtually speaking [everything](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0.8-preview/PRIMER.md#array-notification). E.g. `polymer-element` is gone in favour of `dom-module`. Etc.

The answer to your question is: you should rollback to 0.5 unless you really want to re-write your code from the scratch.

Comment: I was experimenting with 0.8. So I guess I will just wait for the 0.8 official release.

Comment: The 1.0 release of Polymer will be exactly like 0.8 .. read the article that I linked above. Polymer is going a different route in favor of releasing production quality code.